# Traveling to Austria with connection flight in Zurich: Where do I pass through immigration?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, switzerland

I'm from Brazil, and I'm going to Austria for a couple of days. My flight has a connection in Zurich, where I will wait for 2 hours to get the new flight to Vienna. My question is: Will I need to pass through immigration in Zurich, or only in my final destination (Vienna)?

Also (I know it's another question but is some kind related), my luggage, I believe it will be checked-in also to my final destination, but this is always true? Or it depends?

I'm flying with Swiss Airlines (both flights) if it is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are transferring from a non-Schengen flight to an intra-Schengen one, you will enter the Schengen Area in Switzerland. [You will therefore have to go through passport security, and clear immigration, at Zurich airport:](https://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-visitors/arrivals-and-departures/transfers)

> #### Travel outside the Schengen area
>
> If you are travelling to or from countries that do not adhere to the Schengen Agreement you will have to pass through passport control in Zurich. Likewise, transfer passengers travelling to or from the Schengen area from a non-Schengen country will have to pass through passport control in Zurich in future.

Generally speaking, your luggage will be checked through to your final destination if you booked the connecting flights via the same airline, and/or booked with separate airlines but both flights are on the same ticket.

Comment: So this passport security and clear immigration, is where I present my passport, documents and answer the general immigration questions? Thank you!

Comment: @jpgrassi [See wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Travel_in_the_Schengen_Zone) for an explanation on the immigration procedures. Look for the `Entering the Schengen Area` section. If you have more Travel questions, search here first and post them if you don't find your answer. Else [come to the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Welcome. :)